# limit the exponential notation decimal place to 4 in javascript

Tags: javascript, exponent

How to limit the decimal place to 4 in javascript with this type of values? the e is the exponent since I am using power of ten values. `toFixed()` doesn't seem to work.

```
1.0531436913408342e-7
-5.265718456704172e-7
8.425149530726674e7
```

Comment: What would you like from `0.00000010531436913408342`? `0` or `"0.0000"` or `"1.053e-7"` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
   Math.round(val*10000)/10000
```

Comment: hahah! to bad the credit goes to mikko, if only i can check both of your answers... :) thanks for the help

Comment: A cleaner way to do this would be something like:

```Math.round(val*Math.pow(10,limit))/Math.pow(10,limit)```

Answer (score 5):

### use the force, Luke... see `numObj.toExponential(n)`

MDN documents a javascript method specifically for limiting the number of [decimal places to show in exponential notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential):
`*numObj*.toExponential([*fractionDigits*])`

Using your example numbers you get:
`1.0531436913408342e-7.toExponential(4) // returns 1.0531e-7
-5.265718456704172e-7.toExponential(4) // returns -5.2657e-7
8.425149530726674e7.toExponential(4) // returns 8.4251e+7`

Quote from MDN:

> Returns a string representing a Number object in exponential notation
>   with one digit before the decimal point, rounded to fractionDigits
>   digits after the decimal point

Pretty handy!

Answer (score 4):

Try this method: [`value.toPrecision(1 + 4)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Number/toPrecision) for 4 decimal digits.

Comment: This one worked better than the accepted answer for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.round();`

Using `Math.round(x)` will round up or down to the nearest integer (using the classic .5 rule).

You can pass in your own criteria and have it do decimal places. The link below has examples for 1, 2, and 3 decimal places.

[Here is the link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml)