# limit the decimal place in javascript is not working for 4.45678765e-6

Tags: javascript

every time i use the Math.round(4.45678765e-6 * 10000)/10000 it gives me a 0 value but if i remove the e-6 it gives the correct answer 4.4567 what shoul i do? here's my code. the value has the power of 10 something like this 4.45678765x10^-6.

```
<html>    
<script type="text/javascript">

        var x = Math.floor (4.45678765 * 10000)/10000;
        document.write (x);

    </script>
</html>
```

is it even possible to limit the decimal places if the value has an exponent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit the decimal place in javascript is not working for 4.45678765e-6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319715/limit-the-decimal-place-in-javascript-is-not-working-for-4-45678765e-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`4.45678765e-6` is `0.00000445678765`, that number with only five digits after decimal point is `0.00000` so JavaScript is giving you the correct result.

Comment: i thought the same thing, but he's multiplying by 10000, So it's really 0.0445678765, but it's still under 1, which will give 0 anyway using floor.

Comment: @Matt he's multiplying by 10000, rounding and dividing back by 10000 to limit digits after decimal point to 5 and everything is working just right, I don't see any problem here.

Comment: no i don't see a problem either, it's doing exactly what it should, but he thinks he can multiple by 10000 to get the 5 digits. I know what he wants to do, but it's obviously not going to work that way. He says if he leaves out the e-6 he gets the correct answer, so technically he wants to do (4.45678765e-6 * 1e6*10000)

Comment: then how can i make the answer look like this? 4.4567e-6 instead of 4.45678765e-6 or 0.000004457 because i need it to display with and exponent but it should display only four decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

try .toPrecision(5) instead. IE: (4.45678765).toPrecision(5)

Answer (score 1):

use '*numObj*.toExponential([*fractionDigits*])'

your case is its raison d'être, and this overlooked gem seems to be a javascript method rarely given its due!

Quote from MDN:

> Returns a string representing a Number object in exponential notation
>   with one digit before the decimal point, rounded to fractionDigits
>   digits after the decimal point

More simply put, it limits the number of decimal places to show in exponential notation.

```
var x = 4.45678765e-6.toExponential(5) //returns 4.45679e-6
var x = 4.45678765e-6.toExponential(2) //returns 4.46e-6
```

See examples of more rounding with exponential notation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36532545/5440638

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
var x = Number((4.45678765 * 10000)/10000).toFixed(5);
```

The `toFixed( <digit> )` will restrict your value to those digits after decimal point.

Comment: i know that already, the problem is if i put an exponent it returns 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your after but if you want the power;

```
   var f = 4.45678765e-6;
   var exp = Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(f)) / Math.LN10);
   // -6
   var f2 = f * Math.pow(10, -exp);
   // 4.45678765
```