# Limit the decimal place in JavaScript is not working in this math code?

Tags: javascript, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [limit the decimal place in javascript is not working for 4.45678765e-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319343/limit-the-decimal-place-in-javascript-is-not-working-for-4-45678765e-6)

This doesn't give me the answer I would get on a scientific calendar.

```
var myNum = Math.floor (4.45678765 * 10000)/10000;
document.write (x);
```

Is it even possible to limit the decimal places if the value has an exponent?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`4.45678765e-6` means `4.45678765 * 10^(-6)` or `0.00000445678765`, so

```
4.45678765e-6 * 10000 == 0.0445678765
Math.round(0.0445678765) == 0
```

Comment: Wrong exponent. 4.45678765e-6 equals 4.45678765*10^-6. Fixed it for you

Answer (score 1):

4.45678765e-6 * 10000 is still less than 1 (it's 4.45678765e-2 in fact), so calling round or floor will make it 0, and dividing 0 by 10000 is still 0.  In this case, you would need to multiply and divide by 10^10 to get the right answer, but that's not a general solution.  One way is (in pseudocode):

```
counter = 0
while x < 100000:
    x = x * 10
    counter = counter + 1

x = Math.floor(x / 10)
x = x / (10 ^ (counter - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a `toPrecision` function that will allow to you specify *significant figures* rather than *decimal places*.

```
var x = 4.45678765e-6;
console.log(x.toPrecision(4)); // 0.000004457

console.log(x.toFixed(4)); // 0.0000
```